# /linux-.tar.xz: Scheme missing with buildroot

Tags: buildroot

I followed all the instructions mentioned on this link:http://free-electrons.com/doc/training/buildroot/buildroot-labs.pdf
but when I run :

```
make
```

I got these message errors:

```
 >>> linux  Downloading
/linux-.tar.xz: Scheme missing.
--2015-08-10 09:19:10--  http://sources.buildroot.net/linux-.tar.xz
Resolving sources.buildroot.net (sources.buildroot.net)... 176.9.16.109
Connecting to sources.buildroot.net (sources.buildroot.net)|176.9.16.109|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2015-08-10 09:19:10 ERROR 404: Not Found.

make: *** [/home/slim/Downloads/buildroot/output/build/linux-/.stamp_downloaded] Error 1
```

Comment: It seems that BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_VERSION is empty. What version did you choose?